# Calculating OR in function calls

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve a question on LeetCode.com:

> Given an integer array nums, find the maximum possible bitwise OR of a subset of nums and return the number of different non-empty subsets with the maximum bitwise OR.  The bitwise OR of an array a is equal to a[0] OR a[1] OR ... OR a[a.length - 1] (0-indexed).
>   For Input: nums = [3,1], Output: 2.

The code I have is as follows:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int counter;
    
    void helper(vector<int>& nums, int val, int i, int maxval) {
        if(val==maxval) counter++;
        if(i>=nums.size()) return;
        
        helper(nums, val|nums[i], i+1, maxval);
        helper(nums, val, i+1, maxval);
    }
    
    int countMaxOrSubsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        int maxval=accumulate(begin(nums), end(nums), 0, bit_or<int>());
        
        counter=0;
        helper(nums, 0, 0, maxval);
        
        return counter;
    }
};
```

This produces wrong output on the given example `[3,1]`.  However, if I change the helper as below:

```
    void helper(vector<int>& nums, int val, int i, int maxval) {
        if(i>=nums.size()) return;
        
        int currval=val|nums[i];
        if(currval==maxval) counter++;
        
        helper(nums, currval, i+1, maxval);
        helper(nums, val, i+1, maxval);
    }
```

It gives the right answer and gets ACed.  I used print statements, but I do not exactly understand: aren't I doing the same thing in both cases?  Why does the first one produce wrong output?

Thanks!

Comment: Do they specify what they mean by "maximum bitwise OR"? For bitwise OR, that could pretty easily mean either the number with the largest magnitude, or the number with the most bits set.

Comment: I don't follow.  What they mean is roughly "calculate the bitwise OR for all possible subsets, find the maximum value and return how many subsets have this max value".  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, for e.g., for `[3,2,1,5]`, the answer is `6`: The maximum possible bitwise OR of a subset is 7. There are 6 subsets with a bitwise OR of 7: `[3,5]`,`[3,1,5]`,`[3,2,5]`,`[3,2,1,5]`,`[2,5]`,`[2,1,5]`.

Comment: If you try going from your nonworking solution to the working solution in small steps, changing only one thing at a time, you may find that not all of your changes were necessary. This should make it easier to identify exactly what was wrong in the original solution.

Comment: @EOF, my understanding is that in the non-working solution, I am delegating the task of "counter++" to the following recursive call.  This creates issues when each recursive function call reaches the end (`i==nums.size()`); the `val==maxval` condition is true and `counter++` gets incremented.  Am I right?

Comment: I have to admit that your entire approach is not particularly clear, so it would be difficult to find a comprehensible explanation why one variation works and the other does not. I recommend writing code that is understandable by defining invariants, showing that these invariants will enforce that the result computes what it should, and ensuring those invariants are always maintained.

Comment: @J.Doe It is obvious that these two `helper()` variants will give different answer because in first variant you `return` **after** counter is incremented, and in second variant **before** counter is updated. Obvious that they will give different answers because first variant will increase counter more times in total.Hence if second variant givesAccepted result then first will give incorrect result as it gives other value.Difference in counter between this two variants will be only if on very first iteration before return current value will be equal to max value, so sometimes variants are equal